# c++ Proxy wrapper for code injection

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Is there any  non-intrusive way to report which client function is called.
I do not want to change client code. Some some sort of code injection is ok, if I can keep y->hello1() syntax at calling end.

Thanks
Abhi

```
struct client{ 
    void hello1() {cout <<"hi 1";}
    void hello2() {cout <<"hi 2";} 
    };

struct proxy {
    client *target;
    client *operator->() const
        { return target; }
};


void f() {
    client x ;
    proxy y = { & x };

    std::cout <<y->hello1(); //would like proxy to print "hell01 is called
    std::cout <<y->hello2(); //would like proxy to print "hell02 is called
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [XRay](https://llvm.org/docs/XRay.html)?